# Satisfy policies in CXF client

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, ws-security

I'm developing a web service cliente against a wsdl which has the following policies

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" wsu:Id="SecurityServiceSignThenEncryptPolicy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
        <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token11/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:InitiatorToken>
                <sp:RecipientToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Always">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token11/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:RecipientToken>
                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Basic128Rsa15/>
                        <sp:Basic256Rsa15/>
                        <sp:Basic128Sha256Rsa15/>
                        <sp:Basic256Sha256Rsa15/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                <sp:Layout>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Lax/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
                <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                <sp:ProtectTokens/>
                <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
        <sp:Wss10>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss10>
        <sp:Wss11>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
                <sp:RequireSignatureConfirmation/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss11>
    </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="InputBindingPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:EncryptedParts>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OutputBindingPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:EncryptedParts>
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:EncryptedParts>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body/>
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

If I sent a request with SOAP ui I get

```
faultstring>These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token: The received token does not match the token inclusion requirement
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InitiatorToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}RecipientToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}EncryptedParts: 
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body not ENCRYPTED
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}SignedParts: 
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body not SIGNED</faultstring>
```

So I started a CXF client, this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/pathToWsdl?wsdl");
    QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://webservices.provider.com/", "serviceClient");
    Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);

    executeCall(service);
}

public static void executeCall(Service service) {
    //code to get clientInterface;

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(clientInterface);
    Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

    Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps);
    cxfEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(wssIn);
    Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION,
            WSHandlerConstants.TIMESTAMP + " " + WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE + " " + WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPT);

    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "keycliente");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, KeystorePasswordCallback.class.getName());

    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "client-crypto.properties");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_PROP_FILE, "client-crypto.properties");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_KEY_ID, "DirectReference");
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPTION_USER, "tobias");

    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_KEY_TRANSPORT, WSConstants.KEYTRANSPORT_RSA15);

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);

    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

    ServiceRequest request= buildRequest();
    serviceInterface.method(request);
}
```

After execute this client I was able to go one step further, my problem right now is related to the remanet policies that I can't satisfy.

```
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}AsymmetricBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}InitiatorToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}RecipientToken
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}IncludeTimestamp: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
```

With these erros at least I know that the Sign and Encrypt part is working, But I have no idea how build the recipient token and the other thing.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. 
The problem was related to how I was coding the client. WHEN THE POLICY IS CONFIGURED IN THE WSDL the best way is to load it and leaves CXF to do the magic.
If I add an intercetptor it seems that it overrides CXF steps or CXF doesn't do some steps. With this code I was able to make it work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, DatatypeConfigurationException {

    URL wsdlURL = new File("ApiBancosClients.wsdl").toURI().toURL();
    QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://webservices.apibancos.debin.com/", "ApiBancosClient");
    Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);

    callApiBancosClientService(service);
}

public static void callApiBancosClientService(Service service) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    ApiBancosClientInterface apiBancosClientInterface = service.getPort(ApiBancosClientInterface.class);

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(apiBancosClientInterface);
    client.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_PROPERTIES, "client-crypto.properties");
    client.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_PROPERTIES, "client-crypto.properties");
    client.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER, "com.bp.KeystorePasswordCallback");
    client.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_USERNAME, "keycliente");
    client.getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_USERNAME, "keyserver");

    client.getResponseContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_PROPERTIES, "client-crypto.properties");
    client.getResponseContext().put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_PROPERTIES, "client-crypto.properties");
    client.getResponseContext().put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER, "com.bp.KeystorePasswordCallback");

    Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();
    Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    AvisoNuevoDebinRequest avisoDeNuevoDebin = buildRequest();
    apiBancosClientInterface.avisoDeNuevoDebin(avisoDeNuevoDebin);
    System.out.println("FINISH");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SIGNATURE_PARTS and add timestamp element, so it is included.

> {Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp

xxxx.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_PARTS, "{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body;{Element}{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd}Timestamp");